# Dealing with game cursor, not windows cursor

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

Earlier, I had an issue with my Windows cursor being uncoordinated with the game and asked here how I could solve this.  A member suggested me to hide the Windows cursor and create a custom game cursor, so I did this.  However, a new problem occurred.

My game cursor is usually offset to the right of the Windows mouse, so when I want to move the game cursor to the left side of the window and click my left mouse button, it causes a disturbance to the game, such as bringing an application in the background to the top.

Here is a picture of what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Llz.png

As you can see, the game cursor is offset to the right of the Windows cursor, and if I use game cursor to click on something on the left side of the window, the application in the background (Google Chrome in this case), will be brought up to the front, causing disturbance to the game.

Is there anything I can do to use my game cursor without any disturbances?

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried to move everything out of their classes, all into the main Game class.
This fixed the problem, but does not give me an answer to WHY this happens.

The code is exactly the same, it's just organized to separate classes.

So, does anyone know why this is?
Why is using object-oriented programming instead of putting everything in the game class going mess up my mouse coordination and stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would have a texture for you in-game cursor where, for instance, the pixel at [16,16] is where you are "aiming" (the center of a crosshair, for instance). What you owuld to to draw this centered on the mouse is to use Mouse.GetState() to get the position, and then offset the drawing of your mouse-texture by the negative of the "center" of the "aim"-point.

so let's say we make a custom Mouse-Class:

```
public class GameMouse
{
    public Vector2 Position = Vector2.Zero;
    private Texture2D Texture { get; set; }
    private Vector2 CenterPoint = Vector2.Zero;
    public MouseState State { get; set; }
    public MouseState PreviousState { get; set; }

    //Returns true if left button is pressed (true as long as you hold button)
    public Boolean LeftDown
    {
        get { return State.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed; }
    }

    //Returns true if left button has been pressed since last update (only once per click)
    public Boolean LeftPressed
    {
        get { return (State.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) && 
            (PreviousState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released); }
    }

    //Initialize texture and states.
    public GameMouse(Texture2D texture, Vector2 centerPoint)
    {
        Texture = texture;
        CenterPoint = centerPoint;
        State = Mouse.GetState();

        //Calling Update will set previousstate and update Position.
        Update();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        PreviousState = State;
        State = Mouse.GetState();
        Position.X = State.X;
        Position.Y = State.Y;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, Position - CenterPoint, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
}
```